# Image preprocessing before sending it to Tesseract OCR

Tags: javascript, image-processing, canvas, ocr

I'm cropping a part of an image using cropper.js and then trying to extract the text from it using Tesseract js. My issue is that in some cases it does not recognizes simple text, samples below.
[sample-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbbLT.png)
[sample-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcsLl.png)

I also did some tests on Amazon Textract with the same samples and still got the same problems, so my gues is there is something wrong with the cropped images. Does anyone have any experience with preprocessing images before OCR, this also needs to happen with the help of JS

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to isolate just the words? Removing borders or any other kind of noise can improve OCR performance.

The following javascript snippet segments just the letters.

**Result:**

[image: result_1]

[image: result_2]

**Snippet:**

```js
// Canvas and Images 
var canvas1 = document.getElementById("canvas_1"); 
var canvas2 = document.getElementById("canvas_2"); 

// Load Road image 
var imageRoad = new MarvinImage(); 
imageRoad.load("https://i.imgur.com/9cuE5AR.png", imageRoadLoaded); 

// Load Passport image 
var imagePassport = new MarvinImage(); 
imagePassport.load("https://i.imgur.com/cl637On.png", imagePassportLoaded); 

// Find Text regions in the road image 
function imageRoadLoaded(){ 
    var segments = Marvin.findTextRegions(imageRoad, 40, 40, 50, 190); 
    drawSegments(segments, imageRoad); 
    imageRoad.draw(canvas1); 
} 

// Find Text regions in the passport image 
function imagePassportLoaded(){ 
    var segments = Marvin.findTextRegions(imagePassport, 40, 40, 50, 190); 
    drawSegments(segments, imagePassport); 
    imagePassport.draw(canvas2); 
} 

function drawSegments(segments, image){ 
    for(var i in segments){ 
        var seg = segments[i];
    // Skip segments that are too small
        if(seg.height >= 5){ 
            image.drawRect(seg.x1, seg.y1-5, seg.width, seg.height+10, 0xFFFF0000); 
            image.drawRect(seg.x1+1, seg.y1-4, seg.width-2, seg.height+8, 0xFFFF0000); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

```css
body{font-size:12px;}
```

```html
by <a href="https://www.marvinj.org">www.marvinj.org</a></br><br/>
<script src="https://www.marvinj.org/releases/marvinj-1.0.js"></script>
<div style="width:500px; margin:auto">
    <canvas id="canvas_1" width="500" height="300"></canvas>
</div>
<div style="width:601px; margin:auto">
  <canvas id="canvas_2" width="601" height="400"></canvas>
</div>
```